# Sorting xml element attributes values and combining other node(s) data values in output using XSL1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have tried various ways writing xsl script on the below shown xml content.  But not able to get the proper formated output.  I am not able produce proper systanxes in XSL1.0.  Could any one help me out please.

The XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" ?>
<Report xmlns="getItemDetails">
    <table1 v_Head1="Capture Date" Head1_Order="2" v_Head2="End Point Name" Head2_Order="" v_Head3="Secondary ID" Head3_Order="" v_Head4="Individual Name" Head4_Order="1" v_Head5="User Field1"  Head5_Order="3" v_Head6="Check Amount"  Head6_Order="4">
        <table1_Group1_Collection>
            <table1_Group1 MemberName="Memb1" MemberID="61172" MemberTotalAmount="240.00">
                <table1_Group2_Collection>
                    <table1_Group2 DepositNumber="001" DepositID="567328" DepositTotal="135.00">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/08/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="aaa" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="abcabc" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="50.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/08/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="bbb" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="acab" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="25.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/09/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="ccc" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="cdfg" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="60.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                        </Detail_Collection>
                    </table1_Group2>
                    <table1_Group2 DepositNumber="002 " DepositID="567329" DepositTotal="105.00">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/09/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="ddd" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="efgh" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="35.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/10/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="eee" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="hijk" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="70.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                        </Detail_Collection>
                    </table1_Group2>
                </table1_Group2_Collection>
            </table1_Group1>
            <table1_Group1 MemberName="Memb2" MemberID="61173" MemberTotalAmount="275.00">
                <table1_Group2_Collection>
                    <table1_Group2 DepositNumber="003" DepositID="567330" DepositTotal="75.00">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/11/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="fff" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="lmn" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="75.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                        </Detail_Collection>
                    </table1_Group2>
                    <table1_Group2 DepositNumber="004 " DepositID="567331" DepositTotal="200.00">
                        <Detail_Collection>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/11/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="ggg" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="opq" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="150.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                            <Detail v_createdate="03/12/2011" createdate_Order="2" v_EndpointName="null" EndpointName_Order="" v_SecondaryID="" SecondaryID_Order="" v_IndividualName="hhh" IndividualName_Order="1" v_UserField1="rstu" UserField1_Order="3" v_checkamount="50.00" checkamount_Order="4"/>
                        </Detail_Collection>
                    </table1_Group2>
                </table1_Group2_Collection>
            </table1_Group1>
        </table1_Group1_Collection>
    </table1>
</Report>
```

From the above XML file i need to get the following output.

```
MemberName, MemberID, MemberTotal, D_Number, D_ID, D_Total, IndividualName, Createdate, UserField1, Checkamount
Memb1, 61172, $240.00, 001, 567328, $135.00, aaa, 03/08/2011, abcabc, $50.00
Memb1, 61172, $240.00, 001, 567328, $135.00, bbb, 03/08/2011, acab, $25.00
Memb1, 61172, $240.00, 001, 567328, $135.00, ccc, 03/09/2011, cdfg, $60.00
Memb1, 61172, $240.00, 002, 567329, $105.00, ddd, 03/09/2011, efgh, $35.00
Memb1, 61172, $240.00, 002, 567329, $105.00, eee, 03/10/2011, hijk, $70.00
Memb2, 61173, $275.00, 003, 567330,  $75.00, fff, 03/09/2011, lmn,  $75.00
Memb2, 61173, $275.00, 004, 567331, $200.00, ggg, 03/09/2011, opq, $150.00
Memb2, 61173, $275.00, 004, 567331, $200.00, hhh, 03/10/2011, rstu, $50.00
```

Up until D_Total the column names are fixed. 
The column names after 'D_Total' are in sort order (you may see from the xml file the 'order' keyword as suffix to each attribute). 
In this scenario the IndividualName is 1st column. 
And so this will take the first place after D_Total

The attributes Endpointname and SecondaryID are not shown in the output since they don't have any values or may be hidden.

The columns: 'IndividualName', 'Createdate', 'Userfield', 'checkamout' are grouped 
under Deposit details and Member details.
So member details and deposit details will repeat in the corresponding rows.

The totals for Member level (i.e. table1_Group1) will be the sum of Deposit level (i.e. table1_Group2). The Deposit level total amout will be the sum of detail elements (i.e. `<Detail>`).

The XSL1.0 script which i am trying for the above result is as follows: It is only the half part i am able to get correct.  My main challange here is to get the **table1_Group1** *element* values and the **table1_Group2** *element* values (i.e attribute values)  along with **Detail** *element* attributes...

```
     <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:c="getItemDetails">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

                  <xsl:template match="c:Report">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="c:table1"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//c:Detail"/>
      </xsl:template>


      <xsl:template match="c:table1">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[substring(name(), string-length(name())-5)= '_Order' and number(.) = number(.)]      ">
                  <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:template>


         <xsl:template match="c:Detail">
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[substring(name(), string-length(name())-5)= '_Order' and number(.) = number(.)]      ">
                  <xsl:sort data-type="number"/>
              </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:value-of select="../@*[name()=concat('v_',substring-before(substring(name(current()),1),'_'))]"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=-1)">,</xsl:if> 
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you have control of the xml I'd change the xml to column1_Name="IndividualName" IndividualName="ggg" column2_Name="v_createdDate" v_createdDate="03/11/2011"

Comment: Could you post some attempt at xslt? Or do we have to write the complete solution for you?

Comment: So which bits are you having problems with - where do you get stuck?

Comment: I am able to get the values in the output for the details elements... once i am there @ <details elements node Iam unable to get the parent nodes values (which i mean the grouping member values & Deposit values)

Comment: Please can any one check my xslt script to get the appropriate result to get the right result.

Comment: The XSL you posted has a template within a template. That's not a valid stylesheet. Is that really what you have? Also, what does "table1_Group2 element values (i.e attribute values)" mean - are you looking for element values or attribute values?

Comment: 3rd: what does your current stylesheet output (how is it different from the needed output)?

Comment: I am using the sample xsl script code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543099/how-to-sort-the-elements-columns-in-xslt-to-transform-the-xml-file-to-csv-form/7543442#7543442 This solution is simple and clear to understand -- Thanks to @Dimitre Novatchev. 
Every thing looks fine but i was not able to combine the values (attribute values) of parent nodes with the detail element attribute values as shown in the above.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using xslt 1.0, you will need to use grouping. Grouping in xslt 1.0 is done with the muenchian method.

you can find a good example here:

[Grouping with the muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)